# Tomcat cannot find class "InaccessibleWSDLException", glassfish can

Tags: java, tomcat, wsdl, glassfish, webservice-client

I am working with webservices in Java, and right after opening the port and calling the service, I try to catch a "`com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException`".

This worked fine on my dev Glassfish v2 server, but when I shifted my WAR file to Tomcat, I got a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/ws/wsdl/parser/InaccessibleWSDLException
```

I did some Googled it and found out that the JAR **jaxws-rt.jar** had the `InaccessibleWSDLException` class. But including this JAR in my WAR only broke more things.

I would appreciate any help in eliminating this error.

Thanks.

**Additional Info:**

After adding jaxws-rt.jar, I get this on all services, irrespective of whether I catch InaccessibleWSDLException or not:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.XMLStreamBuffer
```

Comment: Please see the additional info. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing another dependency `streambuffer-x.xx.jar` in your classpath. I'm guessing Glassfish was automatically taking care of these dependencies.

Comment: But other services (where I was not catching InaccessibleWSDLException) were working fine before I added jaxws-rt.jar. They did not need streambuffer-x.xx.jar. Now even they don;t work. I'll try adding the jar you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably that you're importing a class starting with `com.sun.`. This is generally bad: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html)

This class is not documented as part of the JAX-WS specification, so I expect this class is part of the JAX-WS implementation in Glassfish; it is unlikely to be present in any other implementation and you should not reference it if you want your code to be portable. I suggest you catch [`WebServiceException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceException.html) instead (which I believe is the parent type).

Comment: Thanks, the class was probably Glassfish specific, because I found it in a jar in the glassfish-v2ur2\lib. Changing references to the 'sun' package might require some work, since we are already in the deployment phase, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all WSDL dependencies, I'm not sure what they are but stream buffer looks like it is, jars can be found here:

http://download.java.net/maven/1/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/jars/

It works in glassfish because it has all those jars installed by default while Tomcat does not.

Comment: Yea, Glassfish has all those JARs those files by default in the ..\glassfish-v2ur2\lib folder. I ended up copying webservices-rt.jar and it worked. For now at least. I hope there aren't any other dependencies. If there are, I'll just copy the entire glassfish-v2ur2\lib.

Comment: Also, the Stream buffer exception probably occurred because jaxws-rt.jar had compatibility issues. No such issues with webservices-rt.jar. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: The stream buffer exception was because webservices-rt.jar contains it and now that you copied it tomcat can find it.